# Swift 4.2 - Getting compiler errors for bridging header files missing in FacebookCore. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

So I recently converted an old swift 3.2 project to a 4.2(quite the jump, i know).

I am getting these errors:[image]

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'app' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'EVReflection/XML'
pod 'FontAwesomeKit', :git => 'https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit.git'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'

pod 'PageMenu', :git=> 'https://github.com/orazz/PageMenu.git'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'RichEditorView'
pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/Swift'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'Fuzi', '~> 1.0.0'
end
```

does this look correct?

Thank you for any insights

Answer (score 1):

First, run `pod install`

And then, check if the version of your pods, probably they are not compatible with Swift 4.2, so you have to update then, or change the "Swift language version" on Pod inspector to swift 3.2 like that way:

Select the "Pod" project in project navigator:

[image]

Select your pod on Targets selector:

[image]

And on "Build settings" tab, find and change the "Swift language version" property:

[image]

**Note:** You can get away of this problem this way, but i highly recommend that you update your pods.

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I may try this.  When you say update your pods, do you mean update cocoapods or each individual pod?

Comment: I mean update each individual pod, check the git page of each pod and update your podfile to the correct version for swift 4.2.

For example, FacebookCore version that implements support to Swift 4.2 is [0.4.0](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/releases)

Comment: You can check your Podfile.lock to check what version of each pod is installed, and i recommend that you make explicit on your Podfile what version you need.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I'm still encountering an issue with a 'TelerikUI/TelerikUI.h' file not found compiler error.  If I accidentally deleted this, how can I get a new copy or clear this error?  I'm going to try restart, clean, build of Xcode and see if that helps for now, but if you have any ideas, please share.

Comment: Try to create a new obj-c "Header-File" named "myproject-Bridging-Header.h" and put `#import <TelerikUI/TelerikUI.h>` on it

Comment: Thank you.  It appears that this file is present with `#import <TelerikUI/TelerikUI.h>` declared, but I think this error is because the search path to the frameworks are wrong.  They are set to DerivedData folder and not the actual directory with the framework/s.